# How to calculate distance between two histograms

Tags: c#

I need to calculate the distance between two histograms using C#.
Has anyone got an idea ?

Comment: This question is vague. What format are your histograms (two lists of numbers?). This is also more a statistics question than a programming question.

Comment: Usually when I need to develop something I start reading about it. Then I try to solve the problem myself. And if I encounter difficulties, I ask a question on StackOverflow by showing my progress, things that I have read and tried and the specific problem I am encountering. And if I have absolutely no clue or time, then I hire a developer to do the job for me. How about you?

Comment: Define a histogram as a point in an n-dimensional vector space, and then associate a metric with that space. (eg, Euclidean metric, Manhattan metric, and so on.) You'll then have a metric space. (And I suppose it will be a Banach space.)

Comment: @Eric Lippert: You need a norm for a Banach space; while there are norms that give you the Euclidean and Manhattan metrics, specifying a metric isn't enough. :-)

Comment: @Jason: True that. It's been a long time since Math 138.

Comment: @EricLippert: I added a square root in order to calculate the Euclidian distance.

Answer (score 1):

May be

```
int distance = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < h1.Length; i++) {
    distance += Math.Abs(h1[i] - h2[i]);
}
```

Or

```
int distance = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < h1.Length; i++) {
    int diff = h2[i] - h1[i];
    distance += diff*diff;
}
distance = Math.Sqrt(distance);
```

EDIT: In response to the comment of Eric Lippert, I added the square root, because this would calculate the distance in a Euclidian vector space.